# Skoruba IdentityServer4 admin project (port 9000) is used

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

i use Skoruba IdentityServer4 fro my projects identity,when i run Skoruba IdentityServer4 [github](https://github.com/skoruba/IdentityServer4.Admin) i see this message

[image]

and check used port in cmd with yhis code

```
netstat -a -b
```

but 9000 port dont exsist in used port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs when you are in a country like Cuba, North Korea, Iran and Syria, etc. that are under sanctions. You must use vpn